# Indie license expired. Unable to use Studio

Tags: xamarin

cross-post from Xamarin Forums

When I bought an annual license last year, my understanding was as per what Xamarin states in their FAQ page (http://xamarin.com/faq):

Your Xamarin license acquired with an annual subscription is perpetual. If you choose not to renew your annual subscription, you will no longer have access to new releases or support, and we will be very sad.

My subscription expired a couple of months ago. When I now try to launch Xamarin Studio and try to launch their EmployeeDirectory sample app, I get the error msg that I have to renew in order to continue using the software.

It's understandable that I should not expect future software updates or support, but to not be able to use the software that I've already paid for seems just plain wrong...

Is there anything I can do about this ?

Comment: Yes, you can contact Xamarin.

Comment: My understanding was that Xamarin Support staff monitors these forums to try and answer relevant questions. Nothing from them yet.

I also noticed that only Business and Enterprise customers get an email address mentioned in their account pages, not Indie customers.

relevant info from their /support page:

Xamarin Business and Enterprise edition customers can contact support using the email address provided in your account page.

is there a generic support@xamarin.com email I can use ? They make it pretty hard to find this info in their support page.

Comment: Yes, use support@xamarin.com.  This week is their user conference, so most of their staff is likely tied up with that.

Comment: Thanks for that info, Jason. I'll send them an email

Comment: Did this happen on windows or mac?

Comment: The Employee Directory application is fairly big. In that sense, it could be the size limit that's preventing you from opening the application on a free subscription.

Comment: @Ingweland this is on windows.

Comment: @EvilBeer It seems strange to prevent sample applications (written by Xamarin) that are meant to help people learn about the power of the framework, to be inaccessible to developers, regardless of account-level. Imagine if a new user just wanted to check out what is possible in Xamarin / downloaded the Employee Dir. app, and saw this error. Not a very good user experience, I think.

Comment: @ino1tn0t Have you tested to confirm my guess? (Treat it as it is - just a guess of what MIGHT be causing it). PS.:) I completely agree with you, from a practical point of view it would not make much sense.

Comment: @EvilBeer , it looks like you're right about the project size being a factor (there might be other factors, which I don't know about) that Xamarin seems to use to decide whether to allow one to launch a solution within Xamarin Studio

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, just install the free version of Xamarin.   https://www.xamarin.com/platform